# malloc-> how much memory is allocated?

Tags: c, malloc

As I know that malloc allocate a specific number of bytes in the memory. However I am trying to use it and I allocate 4 bytes but it gives me NO error when I try to store more than 4 (up to 200 integers) elements in the array!! So in my code I don't need to use realloc!! I'm using Linux by the way. Finally I will pleased to hear any advice from you ... thanks in advance.

tmp.h :

```
 #ifndef TMP_H
 #define TMP_H

 #define MAXLENGTH 4
 #define GROWFACTOR 1.5

 typedef struct stVector
 {
    int *vec;
    int length;
        int maxLength;
 }Vector; 

 Vector newEmptyVector();
 void addElement(Vector *vec, int elt);

 #endif
```

tmp.c :

```
#include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "tmp.h"


    Vector newEmptyVector()
    {
        Vector vec;
        vec.vec = (int*) malloc(0);
        printf("Allocating %d bytes\n", sizeof(int)*MAXLENGTH );
        vec.length = 0;
        vec.maxLength = MAXLENGTH;
        return vec;
    }


    void addElement(Vector *vec, int elt)
    {
        /*if(vec->length == vec->maxLength)
        {
            vec->vec = (int*)realloc(vec->vec,sizeof(int)* vec->maxLength * GROWFACTOR);
            vec->maxLength = vec->maxLength * GROWFACTOR;
        }*/
        vec->vec[vec->length++] = elt;
    }
```

main.c :

```
            #include"tmp.h"
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {

        Vector vector = newEmptyVector();
        printf("The length is %i and maxlength is                                    `                   `%i\n",vector.length,vector.maxLength);
        addElement(&vector,5);
        addElement(&vector,3);
        addElement(&vector,1);
        addElement(&vector,7);
        printf("The length is %i and maxlength is                                            `                       `%i\n",vector.length,vector.maxLength);
        addElement(&vector,51);
 printf("The length is %i and maxlength is %i\n",vector.length,vector.maxLength);      
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        {
            addElement(&vector,i);
 printf("The length is %i and maxlength is %i\n" ,vector.length, vector.maxLength);                                           
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where does it specify it will crash immediately when you corrupt the heap?

Comment: That's what we call **undefined behavior**. Anything can happen.

Comment: When you do `malloc(0)` you allocate *zero* bytes. You will get *either* `NULL` or a valid pointer (that you can pass to `free`) in return. If you do get a non-null pointer in return, it points to that zero-sized memory area you allocated, and which you can't use (since it's of size zero).

Comment: Also, in C [don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Comment: You should also check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc` to make sure they succeeded. This hilignts a problem with the way you call `realloc` since, if it fails, it will have wiped out your only pointer to the memory.

Answer (score 4):

Using memory you haven't allocated invokes undefined behavior. Don't do that. In all likelyhood, Linux has give your program a page of memory, and you haven't overrun that yet. If you touch memory not allocated to your program the OS should cause your program to segfault. But it's possible that any other `malloc`ing you do will also use parts of that page, and you'll end up corrupting your data.

Not having runtime checks for overrunning buffers is part of what makes C fast, but it puts more on the programmer not to do dumb things.

Answer (score 4):

> *"I allocate 4 bytes but it gives me NO error when I try to store more than 4*".

It is not uncommon, when writing to memory that is not owned by the process for it to quietly happen, with no apparent consequences.  But there *are* consequences lurking.  And according to [this](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), anything can happen, and eventually does.

Using an array, created on the heap for simple illustration of UB:

```
int *anyVar = malloc(10 * sizeof(*anyVar));//create space for 10 int
anyVar[10] = 12; //writing to one memory location beyond space allocated 
                 //immediately invoking undefined behavior
```

Writing to memory you do not own invokes *[undefined behavior.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*.  The bad thing is that your results can seem good, and even repeatable for many runs of the code.  But at some point, your code will fail.

Example of memory allocation:  (note:[cast for *malloc()* has been removed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

```
int numIntsInArray = 100;
int *anyVar = malloc(sizeof(int)*numIntsInArray);
if(anyVar)//test pointers to memory before using 
{
    //zero memory before using
    memset(anyVar, 0, sizeof(int)*numIntsInArray);
    anyVar[0] = 1;//first element of anyVar
    anyVar[numIntsInArray-1] = 1000;//last element of anyVar  

    //Free memory when no longer needed:  
    free(anyVar);
}
```

The examples of *bad* code below may result in no compiler warnings, and may seem to run normally, but using them will result in problematic, unpredictable behavior.

```
char * p = "string"; // Badly formed C++11, deprecated C++98/C++03
p[0] = 'X'; // undefined behavior
```

Create an array instead:

```
char p[] = "string"; // Good
p[0] = 'X';
```

C++, you can create/use a standard string like this:

```
std::string s = "string"; // Good
s[0] = 'X';
```

Division by zero results in undefined behavior:

```
int x = 1;
return x / 0; // undefined behavior
```

Some pointer operations may lead to undefined behavior:

```
int arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int* p = arr + 5;  // undefined behavior
```

Leaving a non-void function without returning a value

```
int func(void)
{
    //undefined behavior    
}
```

Unspecified or implementation-defined behavior:

```
printf("%d %d\n", ++n, power(2, n));    //Bad

i = ++i + 1; //Bad

i = i + 1; // Okay
```

Comment: In production code avoid magic number indexes like `anyvar[99]` in the 2nd example when referencing allocated memory. Best to use something like `anyvar[numIntsInArray-1]`.

Comment: @Firstrock - Thanks, not sure why I did not do that at first writing.

Comment: Note that the behavior of `malloc(0)` is implementation-defined: it may return a null pointer, or it may return a pointer which may not be used to access an object. Either way the subsequent `anyVar[0] = 12` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @adabsurdum - I noticed that poor example when I edited the post a few minutes prior, and almost changed it at that point.  Thanks for pushing me over the edge.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that (simply because there is no bound checking in C) no error is raised does not mean that you can safely use memory outside requested bounds. You were lucky not to cause a segmentation fault, you have just fallen into a memory region that is not claimed by your `malloc` (let's say, it's not yours).

You can write there, but there is no guarantee that you won't be overwriting memory assigned to another `malloc` or, conversely, that the "extra" part will not be allocated to some other `malloc`. In your case, the memory region you are writing into appears not to be claimed (yet).

Comment: Is the way that I'm using realloc right to avoid any memory problems that would happen??

Comment: @Stepfano can u help me

Comment: @OmarMuhtaseb - The way you are using realloc above _ vec->vec = (int*)realloc(vec->vec,sizeof(int)* vec->maxLength * GROWFACTOR);_ looks correct. (except you should not cast the output of malloc, calloc or realloc) But the problem is with your initial call of malloc: vec.vec = (int*) malloc(0); Put a value other than 0 there, at least `sizeof(int)*numOfDesiredInts`